# is it possible to attach a window from processing(java 3d) into a swing unit like a panel?

Tags: java, swing

I want to attach another window into my existing `JFrame` or `JComponent` or anything, is there any way to do that?

EDIT: no when i mean as the title says, attack a [Processing](http://processing.org/) 'display window', processing is basically doing stuff with 3d in java and visualising a 3d window. Whenever processing is run it has its own window and i want to attach it on my GUI. How can i do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. do you want to know if it's possible to add a `JPanel` to a `JFrame`? regardless, could you please be more specific, and maybe post some code.

Comment: I added a link to processing.org, and changed WINDOW to 'display window'.  Please don't SHOUT at us, and do not assume that people have any idea what (single word) 3rd party API you are referring to.  In case my WAGs as to your meaning are wrong, feel free to re-edit the question.  **If a 'processing window' is actually a `JWindow` or (looks more like a) `JFrame` & you can get a reference to it, it is a simple matter to call `getContentPane()` to grab it's contents.**

Comment: heheheh sorry for the caps :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`processing.core.PApplet`](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/everything/processing/core/PApplet.html):

> Processing runs in a `Frame` and not a
>   `JFrame`. However, there's nothing to
>   prevent you from embedding a `PApplet`
>   into a `JFrame`, it's just that the base
>   version uses a regular AWT frame
>   because there's simply no need for
>   Swing in that context.