# Processing AnimationThread as a background task in Swing

Tags: java, swing, processing

I am writing an application using *Processing PApplet* ( http://processing.org/ ) inside a *Swing gui* and those two are not a happy marriage. I have a listener for *JButton* which starts a *Swing Worker* to run some long calculations and then plot the outcomes. The problem is that only the calculations run in *Swing Worker* not the Processing *Animation Thread* responsible for plotting, in the result the gui looks like unoccupied (*progress bar* and *Jbutton generateProcessing* are not busy), while in reality it is still plotting for a good minute or so.

When profiling the application I can see *Swing Worker* thread running the calculations, then it dies out and the *done()* methods is executed and prints "Finished" message to terminal, then the *Animation Thread* immediately kicks in (after the plot is ready it doesn't go off but goes to sleep, but that's fine I guess).

The expected behaviuor would be to have the *done()* method called when both *Animation Thread* and the *Swing Worker* jobs are done.

My listener looks like this (*timeSlicerToProcessing* is a class extending *PApplet*)

```
private class ListenGenerateProcessing implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            // Executed in background thread
            public Void doInBackground() {

                    generateProcessing.setEnabled(false);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

                                            //omitted

                        timeSlicerToProcessing.setBurnIn(Integer
                                .valueOf(burnInParser.getText()));

                                                    timeSlicerToProcessing.Impute(); //lengthy computations

                        timeSlicerToProcessing.init();

                return null;
            }// END: doInBackground()

            // Executed in event dispatch thread
            public void done() {

                System.out.println("Finished. \n");
                generateProcessing.setEnabled(true);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);

            }// END: done
        };

        worker.execute();
    }
}// END: ListenGenerateProcessing
```

**Edit:**
Processing does it's plotting in a draw() method, You don't call it directly, from what I know both setup() and draw() get called on init()

This essentially looks like this:

```
public class MyProcessingSketch extends PApplet { 
  public void setup () { 
    size( 200, 200 ); 
    background(100); 
  } 

  public void draw () { 
    drawStuff(); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is that this code:

```
generateProcessing.setEnabled(false);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

should be called in the actionPerformed method *before* the SwingWorker is declared and started, as it needs to be called on the EDT. Your code snippet however doesn't show us where the animation is done, so it's difficult to say what else could be wrong with it.

**Edit:**
Based on your latest comments (which I've added to your original post) I'm still not sure what the problem is, mostly due to my ignorance regarding how pApplets work, however I wonder if the init method should be called on the EDT, perhaps in the SwingWorker's done method.

Comment: Processing does it's plotting in a draw() method, You don't call it directly, from what I know both setup() and draw() get called on init().

Comment: @fbielejec: I have posted your comment above as an edit to your original post, something you should do so that your code can be seen.

Comment: Many thanks for Your comments. I've tried both of your hints, unfortunately that's not it. I can still see "Finished" message and idle progress bar even though I moved the call to init before them. Moreover calling init in done() badly freezes the gui when plotting. If there was a way to somehow call the Processing AnimationThread from the SwingWorker...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. Hopefully someone who knows about the Processing library will contribute. Best of luck with your issue.

Comment: +1 Sorry, not the `Processing` guy, but see also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146986/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-window-from-processingjava-3d-into-a-swing-unit-like/6147329#6147329).

Comment: Hi, no that's not it either, GUI itself runs fine, after some hacks I embedded PApplet into Swing JPanel, even got scrollpanes to work with it. The only problem is in threading right now... I'll try asking at Processing forums maybe, though they usually develop pure Processing apps there...